# foreach через запятую

Tags: jquery

```js
var cells = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8]
var content = ``;
cells.forEach(function(i) {
  content += i;
});
$("div#block").html(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block"></div>
```

Как вывести эти элементы через запятую, чтобы на выходе получился вот такой результат => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Comment: как-то так `[1,2].join(",")` , а forEach тут не нужен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var cells = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8];
console.log(cells + "");
console.log(cells.join(", "));
```